# How to compile a c++ project that requires <winsock2.h>?

Tags: c++, winsock2

I downloaded a project that has these 2 lines in it:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Afxwin.h>
```

I'm confused about on how to compile this, because my standard compiler can't find the selected files.

What do I need to to configure my compiler's search path in order to successfully compile this?

The compiler I tried it with is Dev-C++.

Edit: I'm guessing I have to configure certain libraries to be used when compiling (but which?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building on Windows?

These are Microsoft includes files. If you have Visual Studio, winsock should be available. But for afx (MFC), you need a commercial edition I believe.

If you have a commercial Visual Studio and it still can't find them, it's just a matter of configuring the compiler to include the proper directories (but it should have come that way out of the box).

Comment: Yes, I'm building on Windows with Dev-C++. I don't have Visual Studio. Can you tell me how to build outside Visual Studio?

Comment: Yeah, I looked up  Dev-C++. I would say it's a no-go, unless the use of MFC is very light and you can go through your downloaded program and remove references to it (as well as the #include of course). You can also download a fully functional trial version of Visual Studio - if that would be of use to you.

Comment: Do you think I could compile it with the free (express) version of Visual Studio? Or do I need the commercial version?

Comment: If you go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2890 you can download a 100% functional, legal trial copy of VS2010. (I don't think the free/express editions support MFC).

Comment: Solved with VS2010. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

winsock2.h is part of the Windows SDK and Afxwin.h is the main MFC/ATL include file.

You should be able to download the current Windows SDK from the Microsoft site, but that will not include the MFC code - I'm pretty sure you'll need to have Visual Studio in order to be able to use MFC and ATL.